# Style twitter embedded widget to be horizontal

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm using this twitter embedded widget and I'm wondering if I can possibly get it to display horizontally rather than vertically.

I have instafeed doing this for instagram, but it seems like twitter and facebook are more restrictive and I'm hoping someone knows a good JS workaround.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="400" data-height="500" data-theme="light" href="https://twitter.com/"></a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an example of what you tried and what it's doing?

Comment: Just slightly edited code as well. I tried just applying styles to this but it had no effect. I'm currently trying to do css within the JS block even though I'm more unfamiliar there. I'll try updating with the current direction, just have to clean it up

Comment: You need to give us more than that. Think of it this way, if I were to say "Hey, i modified your code a bit and it worked" but didn't post the code then you would have nothing to go on. Well if we can't see your code and the output then we can't help. Please update the question with code snippets and examples of what you want vs. how it looks.